# How can I plot multiple 3D arrays on a single plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have multiple arrays of 3D data. How can I plot them all on a single plot? The size of the arrays are not equal.

For example:

```
array1_xy = [1 2;3 4;5 6]
array1_z = [10;20;30]
array2_xy = [2 4;5 6;4 6;4 5]
array2_z = [10;20;50;10]
array3_xy = [1 4;1 6;1 3;1 5;1 1;3 4]
array3_z = [10;20;30;10;80;30]
```

How can I plot them on a single 3D plot with different markers?

Answer (score 1):

You want the *[hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)* function.

From the link above:

```
x = -pi:pi/20:pi;
plot(sin(x))
hold on
plot(cos(x))
hold off
```

This will plot `sin(x)` and on the *same* axes it'll plot `cos(x)`.

If you want to plot your arrays with `plot3` function, you can still use `hold on;` and plot them in the same graph.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do a xyz scatter plot(?) in that case, use `plot3`. Details go `help plot3`
Details about markers, go `help plot`

Follow code does what you want.

```
plot3(array1_xy(:,1),array1_xy(:,2),array1_z,'x'); hold on;
plot3(array2_xy(:,1),array2_xy(:,2),array2_z,'o'); 
plot3(array3_xy(:,1),array3_xy(:,2),array3_z,'p');
```